# How to rewrite the intersection of power sets of sets belonging to an indexed family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose that {${A_{i} \in I}$} is an indexed family of sets and $I \ne \varnothing$. Prove that $\cap_{i\in I}A_{i} \in \cap_{i\in I} \mathcal{P}(A_{i})$.

I have a pretty good idea how to to do this proof, but I have a question regarding one of the steps that I have to do.

I was thinking about rewriting the conclusion as 
$$\forall i \in I(\cap_{i\in I}A_{i} \in \mathcal{P}(A_{i}))$$ and then letting $i$ be arbitrary element of $I$. What would I have to prove then?
$$\cap_{i\in I}A_{i} \in \mathcal{P}(A_{i})$$
or 
$$\cap A_{i} \in \mathcal{P}(A_{i})$$since it seems that if $i$ is already an arbitrary element of $I$ there is no point to "letting it run through $I$" using the notation in the first case. Or am I overthinking it and both statements are equal?

Comment: Yes they seem to be equal — what is $\bigcap A_i$ if not the same thing as $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$? The whole thing is simple, just a definition chase. For any $i_0\in I$, $\bigcap_i A_i \subseteq A_{i_0}$, so  $\bigcap_i A_i \in \mathcal{P}(A_{i_0})$, so ... .

Comment: Great thank you, i guess the notation was just confusing me. Would you like to post this as an answer or should I delete the question?

Comment: I'll post it, what the hey ;)

Comment: It would be clear if you did not use the subscript $i$ for 2 different uses in one sentence . Write $\forall i\in I\;(\cap_{k\in I}A_k\in  P(A_i)\;).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are overthinking it, because the proposition is simple.
For any $i_0\in I$, $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \subseteq A_{i_0}$, so $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \in \mathcal{P}(A_{i_0})$. Thus, the intersection of the $A_i$ is a member of every powerset of an $A_{i_0}$, so it's a member of the intersection of those powersets:
$$
\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \in \bigcap_{i_0\in I}\mathcal{P}(A_{i_0}) = \bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{P}(A_{i}),
$$
which is what you wanted to prove.

(Your last concern shouldn't be one: What would $\bigcap A_i$ be, if not an incomplete, probably confusing way of writing $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i$?)